# Getting undefined is not an object evaluating navigation.navigate

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I used This <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('SignInScreen')}> to open other page, But when I click <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('SignInScreen')}> in photos page, I got this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihWSf.png)

The code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, StyleSheet, StatusBar, Image} from 'react-native';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';



const SplashScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const { colors } = useTheme();

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <StatusBar backgroundColor='#009387' barStyle="light-content"/>
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Animatable.Image 
                animation="bounceIn"
                duraton="1500"
            source={require('../assets/fmasdeco.png')}
            style={styles.logo}
            resizeMode="stretch"
            />
        </View>
        <Animatable.View 
            style={[styles.footer, {
                backgroundColor: colors.background
            }]}
            animation="fadeInUpBig"
        >
            <Text style={[styles.title, {
                color: colors.text
            }]}>Stay connected with everyone!</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Sign in with account</Text>
            <View style={styles.button}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('SignInScreen')}>
                <LinearGradient
                    colors={['#08d4c4', '#01ab9d']}
                    style={styles.signIn}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.textSign}>Get Started</Text>
                    <MaterialIcons 
                        name="navigate-next"
                        color="#fff"
                        size={20}
                    />
                </LinearGradient>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </Animatable.View>
      </View>
    );
};

export default SplashScreen;
```

My page SignUpScreen.Js

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default function SignUpScreen() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

Comment: Did you add your SplashScreen Component to your navigation stack?  if not, you can follow this guide https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

Answer (score 0):

Whenever You Navigate From Component which isn't in Your Navigation Container Your Navigation Props Is Undefined Your Splashscreen Component isn't in your Navigation Container May be it is a Child of Screen Thats why You Couldn't get Navigation Prop Pass navigation from from Parent Component where you rendered Splashscreen .

**OR**

You Should Use Use Navigation Hook Provided By React navigation To Navigation Between Screen from Outside of Navigation Container....

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const someComponent = () => { 
  const navigation = useNavigation();

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('SignInScreen')}>
               <Text>Navigation To Sigin Screen</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Hope this would Help...